# Exceed visa by a day Argentina (90 day tourist visa)

Tags: visas, argentina, overstaying

I have an Argentinian tourist visa for 90 days. I entered the country on the 27th of April. Will leaving on the 27 of July (staying one extra day) cause problems at the migration office or will they overlook this detail?

Comment: Are you leaving by plane or by land? Which border crossing? Either way, you will technically have to pay a fine. Whether you actually will be required to do will depend on a bunch of small factors, including the mood of the person doing immigration control.